Minimal transformation of a linear transformation when the null space and an eigenvalue is known.
I am a little confused about this question.
Let $T:\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R^4$ be a linear transformation such that the null space of $T$ is $$\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb R^4~:~4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+x_4=0\}.$$ If rank$(T-3I)=3$ then find the minimal polynomial of $T$.
I understand that $3$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and also that null space of $T$ is of dimension of $3$. I am not sure on how to proceed further.

Yes, $\dim\ker T=3$. Let $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ be a basis of $\ker T$. And let $v_4\in\Bbb R^4$ be an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $3$. Then $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ and the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is$$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}.$$Clearly, $M.(M-3\operatorname{Id})=0$; in other words, $M^2-3M=0$. So, the minimal  polynomial of $T$ divides $\lambda^2-3\lambda$. Since $M$ is not a scalar matrix, the degree of its minimal polynomial is greater than $1$. So, the minimal polynomial has to be $\lambda^2-3\lambda$.

Thank you very much.

I'm glad I could help.
